# Disabling 2g/3g android

Tags: android, eclipse, 3g

I'm trying to make a button that I can easily push to turn on or off the 3g for an app I am making. Does anyone know how to do this or can send me in the right direction? Also I'm using eclipse. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[APNdroid](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.code.apndroid&hl=en) and [APN OnOff](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.curvefish.widgets.apnonoff&hl=en) do this. They both change the [APN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Point_Name) for the mobile network to a valid/invalid value on click. The end results is having a data stream or not.

Comment: Ok thank you for your quick response I understand. I just downloaded the apndroid but I still can browse the internet.

Comment: @Jonathan: Have you explicitly disabled data from the app or the widget? They both work for me. (Also make sure you are not on wifi.)

Comment: yes the notification pops up saying that there is no network but I can still browse the web and the widget app redirects me to the system settings as inazaruk stated.

Comment: I have verizon wireless and the moto droid. That might be the reason. But how r they able to disable the 3g on some phones?

Comment: @Jonathan: Can you provide your APN name (Wireless & Networks->Mobile Networks->Access Point Names-><carrier>->APN) when the widget is turned on/off. (not the data switch in system settings)? It could be a carrier related problem but this is not reflected in the market comments for these two and other apps with similar functionality.

Comment: @Jonathan: It is working as expected. I have no idea why you can still connect.

Comment: I unserstand how their app works now. Its funny I even created my own apn and deleted verizons apn and I still got 3g. I also deleted all apns and it still worked.

Comment: Could it be that since my phone is rooted it doesn't work? All I want to know now is how can I disable or change up the apn like apndroid for my app.